# How can I find out who causes µTorrent / Bittorrent traffic on my WiFi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

I am currently using a Linksys wrt54g wireless router along with a ARRIS CM550A Cable Modem that provides 12 MB/s download speed and upload speed of 1 MB/s.

The Internet connection is functioning well; however as soon as one of my roommates connects to the WiFi it gets extremely slow. I think that a torrent application is causing this; I am not sure though.

[image]

So I am wondering: is there a way to find out which IP address / MAC address is consuming the most bandwidth? Or which application is using a certain amount of bandwidth?

Comment: Did you think to ask your roommates what they are doing when they come home and connect to the internet? Ask them to stop hogging bandwidth or lose internet privileges.

Comment: Disable wireless OR configure wireless to work for only some MAC addresses. (My older Linksys router has that feature, it seems to be standard) Then don't add your roommate's computer to the list. Problem solved.

Comment: Is your system windows 8, or is your roomate's system? The fact that its windows 8 seems to have been tacked on as an afterthought.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek my system is Windows 8. The reason I stated this was because there might be some incompatible software out there.

Comment: I really don't think that Windows 8 is a relevant tag in this instance.

Comment: @KronoS removed

Comment: The best way is process of elimination.  Change the password one month, tell only a single person the password, block all other MAC addresses except yours and this persons.  If the traffic situation stops you can add an additional person that month.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check out the router diagnostics / statistics pages to figure this out.

Also, a stronger firewall can guarantee to kill this kind of unwanted traffic, especially if you also kill off unwanted outgoing traffic and not only unwanted incoming traffic...

Answer (score 1):

The default Linksys firmware can tell you what computers are connected to the network, but it doesn't really have that much to tell you what the computers are doing.

If you go to **Administration** > **Log** you can enable a log which will show *some* details about the traffic being passed over the network, which *might* be enough for you to identify the offending roommate.

Once you've identified him, have him configure his torrent client to a much lower download/upload bandwidth limit.

And finally, if he's unwilling to adjust his settings, then set QoS up on the router. [This is really intricate and will require a lot of trial and error](http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/using-qos-tutorial-and-discussion.28349/), but you can get very good results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can check the bandwidth used by each, but you can limit it.

Enable [QOS](http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Quality_of_Service_Networking) and setup QOS rules in your wireless router(and limit bandwidth) to avoid this situation.

[How do I Configure Linksys QoS for Torrent?](http://www.ehow.com/how_6917704_do-configure-linksys-qos-torrent_.html)